# Splicing doesn't work in ternary conditional

Tags: javascript

Trying to remove any number that appears in both arrays:

```
function diff(args) {

  var diff = [].concat.apply([],arguments).reduce(
    function(result, current) {

      console.log("result: " + result);
      console.log("current: " + current);
      console.log("result.indexOf(current): " + result.indexOf(current));

      return result.indexOf(current) === -1 
      ? result.concat(current) 
      : result.splice(result.indexOf(current), 1);
    }, []
  );
  console.log("diff: " + diff); 
  return diff;
}

console.clear();
diff([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

However the console indicates that:

```
Console was cleared
result: 
current: 1
result.indexOf(current): -1
result: 1
current: 2
result.indexOf(current): -1
result: 1,2
current: 3
result.indexOf(current): -1
result: 1,2,3
current: 5
result.indexOf(current): -1
result: 1,2,3,5
current: 2
result.indexOf(current): 1
result: 2
current: 1
result.indexOf(current): -1
result: 2,1
current: 4
result.indexOf(current): -1
diff: 2,1,4
```

Why is the slice statement being ignored and rather resetting my result var with the current var?

Ideally I thought that result.splice(result.indexOf(current), 1) on the first find would result in:

1,3,5

not

2

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading: `slice` and `splice` are different.

Comment: Sorry that's what was actually tripping me up. The similar names and not understanding the difference.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#splice` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) the slice of the array which was removed, and you're assigning it to the result.

You should use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead:

```js
function diff(args) {

  var diff = [].concat.apply([], arguments).reduce(
    function(result, current) {

      console.log("result: " + result);
      console.log("current: " + current);
      console.log("result.indexOf(current): " + result.indexOf(current));
      
      var index = result.indexOf(current);

      return index === -1 ?
        result.concat(current) :
        result.slice(0, index).concat(result.slice(index + 1));
    }, []
  );
  console.log("diff: " + diff);
  return diff;
}

console.clear();
diff([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now that's the expected behaviour of [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), whose...

> Return value: an array containing the deleted elements

We can better see this is we swap that ternary for an `if`. This is what you have now:

```
if (result.indexOf(current) === -1) {
    return result.concat(current)
} else {
    return result.splice(result.indexOf(current), 1);
}
```

So, as you can see, you are returning the deleted element.

What you want is this:

```
if (result.indexOf(current) === -1) {
    return result.concat(current)
} else {
    result.splice(result.indexOf(current), 1);
    return result
}
```

Now, you are deleting the element, and only after returning the resulting array.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
function diff(args) {
  var diff = [].concat.apply([], arguments).reduce(
    function(result, current) {

      console.log("result: " + result);
      console.log("current: " + current);
      console.log("result.indexOf(current): " + result.indexOf(current));

      if (result.indexOf(current) === -1) {
        return result.concat(current)
      } else {
        result.splice(result.indexOf(current), 1);
        return result
      }
    }, []
  );
  console.log("diff: " + diff);
  return diff;
}

console.clear();
diff([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```